# Shared library and Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I recently started to use Android NDK and I’m facing some problems with shared libraries.
I created a project with Eclipse that allows me to use NDK and natives functions. But now, I would like to use another shared library that I created with QtCreator.
So here is my question. Is that possible to include a shared library to my NDK project, even if I didn’t invoke ndk-build to create it?
Let’s take an example. If I create a simple shared library like that:

```
g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libapi.so MyDLL.cpp
```

Could I be able to use it on my NDK project like this (Android.mk):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := api
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := ../sharedLibs/libapi.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := dbapi
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := dbapi.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        += ../includes
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := api

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And of course, could I be able to use its functions on my native NDK side?

Using this method, I'm facing this error when I try to build my Eclipse project:

```
/libs/armeabi-v7a/libapi.so: File format not recognized
```

I thought my shared lib was not compatible with ndk-build (true, false?).
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you build your shared lib? Is it compiled for arm, with NDK? 
If not, it cannot work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I built it with this single command line: `g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libapi.so MyDLL.cpp`. So according what you are saying, I cannot include this library if I don't use the ndk builder?

Comment: So you compile on linux, with g++ from your distribution, not the g++ from the ndk ?

Comment: I'm on windows, using cygwin, without ndk g++. I tried to create a Android.mk for my C++ project and I invoked ndk-build... and it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The people in the comments are indicating that you have almost certainly compiled for x86 instead of arm.  (You say you are using cygwin with Windows, which will compile to x86 by default unless your windows box is an arm box, which I am guessing is not the case.)

Inside the Android ndk is a script called make-standalone-toolchain.sh.  If you are in the current directory where your ndk is installed, you can use this by typing:

```
./android-ndk-r9/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=<your desired android platform> --install-dir=<location where you want android toolchain>
```

This will create a set of build tools which you can use to build arm binaries to run on your device.  These tools will be named things like, e.g.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

Put those tools in your path and use them to build your library.

I don't know whether cygwin includes a "file" command, but you may be able to determine the architecture of your shared library by typing:

```
file libapi.so
```

If it says it's arm, you're good.  If it says x86, it won't work (except on an x86 android device, that is).

Comment: Indeed, `file libapi.so` returns me `x86-64, for MS Windows`. Thanks for the explanations.